# Interaction with an SPL token using Solang

Tags: solang

I am looking to take an SPL token as a payment in my Solang contract, but the `transfer` function is marked as `internal`. (`function transfer(address from, address to, address owner, uint64 amount) internal`)

How do I transfer an SPL token (or get the value of native SOL sent) in a program? Is this possible in Solang?

Answer (score 0):

The function is marked internal because you are supposed to call it from inside a Solidity contract.

On Solana's examples repository, there is a basic Solidity contract that shows how to interact with SPL-tokens.

https://github.com/solana-developers/program-examples/blob/main/tokens/transfer-tokens/solang/solidity/transfer-tokens.sol

Let me know if it helps.